# Regex to retrieve dataset and table name using dot in SQL BigQUery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an input table which has a list of all queries run in Bigquery. I need to create two columns one with the dataset name and other with table name.

The queries example is as follows (some could be nested). I need to separate the dataset name and tablename using the dot in the string

| Queries | dataset | table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| select * from advp.accounts ; | advp | accounts |
| select * from gqd.customers where id in (select id from gwq.facts) ; | gqd | customers |
|  | gwq | facts |
| create table hsq.sales (id int64, ss string); | hsq | sales |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all) to extract all instances of "*<database>.<table>*", then unnest the corresponding arrays.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Queries, r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.') AS db_names, 
              REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Queries, r'(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)') AS table_names
    FROM tab
)
SELECT cte.Queries, dataset, table_
FROM cte, cte.db_names AS dataset, cte.table_names AS table_
```

Comment: This doesnt work in case of nested queries. It only separates the first instance  of dataset.tablename

Comment: You're correct, I've updated the query accordingly. Does it work correctly? (can't test it myself)

Comment: Great!! Thank you for your prompt response.